# 9-patch padding doesn't adjust correctly

Tags: android, nine-patch

Adding a 9-patch:

[image]

Seems ok here:

[image]

However, after adding `android:padding="5dp"`, the padding doesn't just happen around the content. Also, the arrow stretches a bit. Is my 9-patch drawn incorrectly?

[image]

TextView:

[image]

Comment: 1) I used Android studio to draw the lines 2) the padding should work on the content only, not adjust the background

Comment: The 9-patch was fine. I just wrapped it in a FrameLayout. Check my answer

Comment: You don't have to manually specify the padding in your layout, if you already have padding in your 9-patch!

Answer (score 1):

This ended up doing it. I guess the adding the background 9-patch directly to the TextView doesn't work. Just wrap it in a FrameLayout

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:background="@drawable/notification_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_number_left"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: One other thing you could try is doing paddingLeft=10dp and paddingRight=5dp.  That might reduce your xml by one item.  But if you got it working, then I'd just keep that. :)

Comment: From my experiences setting padding in the xml *overrides* what's defined in 9-patch. Are you sure the FrameLayout (hack) works across different devices? I bet you it's not going to render the same from JB to Lollipop.

Comment: Right, but the padding is in the child view, while the 9-patch is in the parent. Does that make a difference? Also, I've tried on Kit Kat and Lollipop with positive results

Comment: @AaronGillion is the proper solution to add the padding via 9-patch lines (left and bottom) and add the padding by not making them go all the way up or down?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that your background is on the FrameLayout. I'm glad 9-patch is working for you. In a lot of the complex applications I've created with a lot of layouts, and also some simpler apps, 9-patch padding for me has been ignored in a lot of situations. Margins, nested views, gravity, and align-components have all caused problems with 9-patch padding for me. I learned to avoid it completely. Not sure if this is an Android Studio-specific problem.

Comment: @ono thank you for the interesting question. Just out of interest, did you try adding padding through 9-patch mechanisms (which is *right* and bottom lines)? From you images I feel like Aaron may be right and xml padding overrides that of 9-patch because on the 3rd screenshot it looks like padding is added from all sides of the bounding square (with no consideration for the 9-patch bottom padding line).

Comment: @Android777 adjusting the right and bottom lines does have an impact. this may be a better way to go than wrapping it in a FrameLayout then doing padding on the child view

Comment: @ono yep if it works, then apparently it's a big deal for the layout performance not needing to wrap your textviews in their own view groups each time :) if you get the expected effect, you may want to amend your answer for future generations :)

Comment: @Android777 this does have it's disadvantages: for example, you will need to make sure the bottom and the right line are the same length and position to get even padding on all sides. Also, you can't change the padding if you re-use that 9-patch since you're relying on the padding created by the lines.

Comment: @ono agreed, fair enough